# Get only male member of a group in FB graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to get only male member of a facebook group using graph API

Answer (score 1):

There isn't. You can't get gender of people without them login to your app

Answer (score 1):

If you have an app which can use Graph API v1.0, you can use FQL to do this:

```
select uid, sex from user where uid in (select uid from group_member where gid={group_id}) and sex='male'
```

where `{group_id}` is the object_id of the group.

If you only have >=v2.0, then it's not possible to get the gender from the Graph API unless you'd have gathered the `public_profile` permission from ALL group users via an app.